# Magento 1.9.2. - Delete all second images of the products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, products, image

During an import of all the new products in the **"media gallery"** section of each product, a second image path has been added for error. 
I want to avoid manually deleting all the second images of each product. Is there a way to automatically delete all the second images of each product without touching the main image with "order: 1"?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I imagine something like this would work.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");

foreach($collection as $product) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $entityTypeId = $product->getEntityTypeId();
    $mediaGalleryAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->loadByCode($entityTypeId, 'media_gallery');
    $gallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach ($gallery as $image) {
        if($image['position'] != "1") {
            $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend()->removeImage($product, $image->getFile());
        }
    }
    $product->save();
}
```

What I'm doing here is looping through all of the products and then through their images and removing any that do not have a position of 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried your code but it gives me as an error: "Undefined variable: i". Is it possible to create an if in your code? I would like to be able to tell Magento to delete images of products that do not have "order: 1" in the position of media_gallery_position

Comment: Try my updated solution, but back up your work first to be on the safe side!

Comment: I'm doing the tests locally for now. Anyway I tried your code but nothing has changed for now. I uploaded the code to a php file and uploaded it to the root of the site, also loading Mage.php but nothing happened. Blank page is enough. When I returned to the backend I saw that the second image of the products was always there.

Comment: Try my updated code! I'm not sure why using the media API doesn't work, but this method definitely does.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I tried your code again. The page continues to load endlessly, as if it were looped. After 20 minutes i tried to saw in "manage products" and the product has ever the second image.

Comment: It'll take a long time if you have a lot of products. Have a look at one of the first products on your site and see if the images have been removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72799/discussion-between-liam-mcarthur-and-gabriel91).